# Where is the kmalloc used when open a file for linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I know that when we call open there will be a struct file in slub in linux kernel. I want to know that address of that struct. So I need to find the `kmalloc` where it allocates that struct. But I can't find it. I thought it would be somewhere like `fs/open.c` but there isn't this `kmalloc`. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open` syscall (in [`fs/open.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/open.c#L1114)) calls [`do_sys_open`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/open.c#L1086). There, the first `struct file`-related line is

```c
struct file *f = do_filp_open(dfd, tmp, &op);
```

[`do_filp_open`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/namei.c#L3532) is defined in `fs/namei.c`, and calls [`path_openat`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/namei.c#L3474) to obtain the `struct file *` that it returns. In that function, an empty `struct file *` is obtained through

```c
file = get_empty_filp();
```

[`get_empty_filp`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/file_table.c#L103) (from `fs/file_table.c`) uses `kmem_cache_zalloc` to allocate zeroed memory [with caching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22370102/1106415) and then initializes the `struct file` (including all the locks etc.)